# How can I access a deep nested json i.e. soap xml response which is converted to json

Tags: arrays, json, angular, soap, subscribe

My json file is here:

```
{
   "identifier":0,
   "modifiedDate":null,
   "version":0,
   "action":null,
   "pageDTO":null,
   "sortFilterDTO":null,
   "userFilterDTO":null,
   "securityToken":null,
   "createdBy":null,
   "trackingId":null,
   "resultList":[
      {
         "administrativeRecord":null,
         "dataRecord":{
            "baseDTO":{
               "identifier":97375,
               "modifiedDate":null,
               "version":1,
               "action":null,
               "pageDTO":null,
               "sortFilterDTO":null,
               "userFilterDTO":null,
               "securityToken":null,
               "createdBy":null,
               "trackingId":null,
               "queryDocumentDTO":null,
               "otherInfo":null,
               "responseType":null,
               "cancelledDate":null,
               "cancelledDateGMT":null,
               "flightAirports":[
                  {
                     "identifier":120572,
                     "modifiedDate":null,
                     "version":2,
                     "action":null,
                     "pageDTO":null,
                     "sortFilterDTO":null,
                     "userFilterDTO":null,
                     "securityToken":null,
                     "createdBy":null,
                     "trackingId":null,
                     "aircraftType":"100",
                     "aircraftSuffix":"TRY",
                     "arrivalAirport":"DEL",
                     "departureAirport":"BOM",
                     "autoload":null,
                     "reverseDeadloadMapInd":null,
                     "horizonPrinterInd":null,
                     "estimatedDepartureDateTime":1509636600000,
                     "estimatedDepartureGMTDateTime":1509616800000,
                     "estimatedArrivalDateTime":null,
                     "estimatedArrivalGMTDateTime":null,
                     "scheduledArrivalDateTime":1509643800000,
                     "scheduledArrivalGMTDateTime":1509624000000,
                     "scheduledDepartureDateTime":1509636600000,
                     "scheduledDepartureGMTDateTime":1509616800000,
                     "flightAirportWBDTO":{
                        "identifier":0,
                        "modifiedDate":null,
                        "version":0,
                        "action":null,
                        "pageDTO":null,
                        "sortFilterDTO":null,
                        "userFilterDTO":null,
                        "securityToken":null,
                        "createdBy":null,
                        "trackingId":null,
                        "aircraftType":null,
                        "aircraftSuffix":null,
                        "aircraftTypeRevisionId":0,
                        "flightNotes":null,
                        "flightDocMessages":null,
                        "aircraftRegistration":null,
                        "aircraftRegistrationId":null,
                        "stabTrimSettingSelMethod":null,
                        "flapSetting":null,
                        "thrustSetting":null,
                        "cabinCrewFemale":0,
                        "cabinCrewMale":0,
                        "flightDeckCrewFemale":0,
                        "flightDeckCrewMale":0,
                        "flightTypeIdentifier":null,
                        "flightTypeSelMethod":null,
                        "flightTypeId":null,
                        "loadConfig":null,
                        "loadConfigSelMethod":null,
                        "loadConfigId":null,
                        "pantryCode":null,
                        "pantryCodeSelMethod":null,
                        "pantryCodeId":null,
                        "crewCodeSelMethod":null,
                        "crewCode":null,
                        "crewCodeId":null,
                        "crewWeightProfile":null,
                        "crewWeightProfileSelMethod":null,
                        "crewWeightId":null,
                        "paxWeightProfile":null,
                        "paxWeightProfileSelMethod":null,
                        "paxWeightProfileId":null,
                        "seatPlan":null,
                        "seatPlanSelMethod":null,
                        "seatPlanId":null,
                        "seatConfigSelMethod":"Manual",
                        "seatingConfig":null,
                        "seatConfigId":null,
                        "cargoWeightAllotmentSelMethod":null,
                        "cargoWeightAllotment":0.0,
                        "mailWeightAllotment":0.0,
                        "mailWeightAllotmentSelMethod":null,
                        "assignedLoadControlAgent":null,
                        "flightTaskTableName":null,
                        "flightTaskTableNameSelMethod":null,
                        "genderBasedPaxIndicator":"not-selected",
                        "deadloads":null,
                        "fixedItems":null,
                        "adhocItems":null,
                        "finalizedStatusList":null,
                        "fuelfigures":null,
                        "passengerInformationDTOList":null,
                        "seatDetailDTOList":null,
                        "seatSelectionTypeIndicator":"not-selected",
                        "noFitPositions":null,
                        "flightAlerts":null,
                        "areaSeatingDistributions":null,
                        "balanceResultDetails":null,
                        "regulatedZeroFuelWeight":0.0,
                        "regulatedTakeOffWeight":0.0,
                        "regulatedLandingWeight":0.0,
                        "regulatedRampWeight":0.0,
                        "finalLoadSheetGenReqd":"not-selected",
                        "overridePositions":null,
                        "invalidatedPaxInfo":"not-selected",
                        "ckiEnabledInd":"not-selected",
                        "autoPlannedBagIndicator":"selected",
                        "dynamicLoadingInd":"not-selected",
                        "cpmRecievedInd":"not-selected",
                        "ldmRecievedInd":"not-selected",
                        "somRecievedInd":"not-selected",
                        "uplineAirportStatus":null,
                        "overridePositionsInd":"not-selected",
                        "flightEvents":null,
                        "flightAptScheduledTimeDTOs":null,
                        "rowDistributionIndicator":"not-selected",
                        "distributionAutoIndicator":"not-selected",
                        "actualPaxCount":0,
                        "estimatedPaxCount":0,
                        "alertsCount":1,
                        "flightScheduledTaskDTOList":null,
                        "updateNumber":0,
                        "flightMsgRefDTOList":null,
                        "costPenalty":null,
                        "cmapIntegrationStatus":null,
                        "cmapErrorList":null,
                        "rtowfromBusinessRule":false,
                        "oprAdjustmntPresent":false,
                        "aircraftRegPresent":false,
                        "mailWtAllotmentPresent":false,
                        "oprLimitsPresent":false,
                        "flightCrewPresent":false,
                        "cargoWtAllotmentPresent":false,
                        "implVersion":1,
                        "dtodetails":"Base DTO details : Identifier :: 0, Version :: 0",
                        "futureData":null,
                        "dataVersion":0
                     },
                     "aircraftRegistration":"EP-IAH",
                     "cancelledDate":null,
                     "flightLegNumber":1,
                     "gateAssignment":null,
                     "parkingPosition":null,
                     "seatingConfig":"C22 Y417",
                     "checkInStatus":null,
                     "cancelReferenceNumber":null,
                     "wnbStatus":"OPEN",
                     "captainName":null,
                     "wbMechanizedInd":null,
                     "ckiMechanizedInd":null,
                     "cancelledDateGMT":null,
                     "flightRoute":"BOM-DEL",
                     "assignedAgentCode":"NHO6Y",
                     "assignedAgentName":null,
                     "assignedBySupervisorInd":"selected",
                     "ignoredLcpReason":null,
                     "isLcpSupported":null,
                     "stabTrimRequired":false,
                     "seatDestinationRequired":false,
                     "airportDataModified":false,
                     "flightAirportCancelled":false,
                     "implVersion":1,
                     "dtodetails":"Base DTO details : Identifier :: 120572, Version :: 2",
                     "futureData":null,
                     "dataVersion":0
                  }
               ],
               "flightDate":1509561000000,
               "flightDateGMT":1509561000000,
               "flightSuffix":null,
               "handledAirlineCode":"J2",
               "airlineNumber":"10441",
               "airlineName":null,
               "handledAirlineCodeId":54028,
               "flightNumber":2000,
               "emergencyLockIndicator":"not-selected",
               "flightMonitorAutoInd":"not-selected",
               "firstMechnizedLegNumber":null,
               "firstAirportVersion":2,
               "firstAirportIdentifier":120572,
               "validateLicenseRequired":false,
               "dtodetails":"\nBusiness Identifier \nFlightProfileDTO : FlightNumber :: 2000, FlightDate :: Thu Nov 02 00:00:00 IST 2017, FlightDateGMT :: Thu Nov 02 00:00:00 IST 2017\nFlightLegNumber :: 1, DepartureAirport :: BOM, ArrivalAirport :: DEL, ScheduledDepartureDateTime :: Thu Nov 02 21:00:00 IST 2017, ScheduledDepartureGMTDateTime :: Thu Nov 02 15:30:00 IST 2017, Aircraft type :: 100, Aircraft suffix :: TRY, Aircraft registration :: EP-IAH, Seating config :: C22 Y417",
               "implVersion":1,
               "futureData":null,
               "dataVersion":0
            },
            "implVersion":1,
            "futureData":null,
            "dataVersion":0
         },
         "implVersion":1,
         "futureData":null,
         "dataVersion":0
      },
      {},
      {}
   ],
   "userData":null,
   "paginationAttrGroupDTO":{
      "start":"1",
      "end":"3",
      "total":"3",
      "orderBy":null
   },
   "recordCount":3,
   "dtodetails":"3",
   "implVersion":1,
   "futureData":null,
   "dataVersion":0
}
```

Comment: your JSON file is here and what you want to do ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I want to access the resultdata records alone from the json file using angular 9. Need to segregate the data